# Problema con implementación de anuncio intersticial en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy intentando implementar anuncios en mi app, primero un anuncio intersticial. He seguido los pasos de la documentación oficial pero me da el error "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet" siempre y no carga el anuncio.

He implementado mi ID en el manifest:
[image: Manifest]

He añadido las dependencias al gradle:
[image: Gradle]

Y este es mi código que he metido en una función. Todo el código es de la documentación oficial de Google, y estoy usando el ID para cargar anuncios proporcionados por Google para que no haya problemas:

```
fun cargarAnuncio(adRequest: AdRequest){
    var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
            Log.d("TAG", adError?.message)
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad was loaded.")
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
    })

    mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad was dismissed.")
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad failed to show.")
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }
    }

    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
    }
}
```

También he inicializado esto que me pedía

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si analizas el mensaje:

> "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet" ("El anuncio intersticial aún
> no estaba listo)"

indica que el anuncio no estaba listo para ser mostrado, debes esperar a que el anuncio este listo para mostrarse en pantalla.

[Lo que describe la documentación](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#show_the_ad) en realidad debería también revisar si el anuncio ha sido cargado mediante el método `isLoaded()`:

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
  mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
}
```

Pero **lo ideal es que muestres el anuncio cuando esta cargado y esto debe realizarse dentro del callback `onAdLoaded()`**, usa el método show() y el contexto de la Activity `.show(this@MainActivity)` :

```
 override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad was loaded.")
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd

            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
            }

        }
```

De esta forma se mostraría el anuncio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Documentación: [**Insterstitial Ads**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)

Comment: Hola. No sé porque pero me da error en mInterstitialAd?.show(this) al meter el if-else en onAdLoaded. Concretamente me marca el error en el this y me da el error "Create extension function InterstitialAd.show". Este error no se produce cuando yo tenía el if-else fuera de onAdLoaded. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Comment: Perdón debes usar como contexto this@MainActivity ya que este método necesita el contexto de la Activity,.